# Spring command line JSON config containing array

Tags: spring, grails, spring-boot, configuration

I am using Grails 3 Elasticsearch plugin with Springs external JSON configuration by setting `spring.application.json` as system property.
The properties are available in the application but I can't find a way to initialize an array properly.

What I am trying to accomplish is to override the default values of the `hosts` property specified in my `application.yml`:

```
environments:
  development:
    elasticSearch:
      client:
        hosts:
          - {host: "myhost.com", port: 9300}
          - {host: "anotherhost.com", port: 9300}
```

I am setting the property from the command line as follows:

```
-Dspring.application.json={"environments":{"development":{"elasticSearch":{"client":{"hosts":[{"host":"override1.com", "port":9000},{"host":"override2.com", "port":9100}]}}}}}
```

I would expect `environments.development.elasticSearch.client.hosts` to contain an array like it does when initialized from the `application.yml`, but in fact `environments.development.elasticSearch.client` containes `host[0]` and `host[1]`, where each contains the host and the port. The `host` array from the `yml` file is still there.

How can I achieve the same behavior using the command line as with the `application.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this the same way that you would if it was set in a .properties file, using a list:

```
-Denvironments.developmet.elasticSearch.client.hosts={"host":"override1.com", "port":9000},{"host":"override2.com", "port":9100}
```

and I believe you can also do it as an environment variable...

```
set ENVIRONMENTS_DEVELOPMENT_ELASTICSEARCH_CLIENT_HOSTS='{"host":"override1.com", "port":9000},{"host":"override2.com", "port":9100}'
```

There may need to be some quotes around parts of these depending on the shell you are in, the OS, etc.